# :focus selector not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, focus, accordion

I'm using :focus to color the parent page item on my sidebar accordion drop downs. (i.e click Photography on the sidebar )

When you click on the accordion items I want to maintain the background colour while it is active.

It works fine on Chrome & Firefox but not Safari, any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is a URL to the page I am working on;

http://lap.dev.gridhosted.co.uk/b/portfolio-gallery/

[image: screenshot]

Comment: did you try with to add the same style also for `:active`?

Comment: @Fabio Yes, didn't work also.

Comment: does any one know of a jquery fix I could implement to style the previously clicked item?